# Kernel of a linear operator on subset poset

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics

Let $X$ be the set $\{1,2,...n\}$ and $X_i$ be set of all $i$-element subsets of $X$. Define a real vector space $V_i$ with $X_i$ as the basis. Let $T :V_i \mapsto V_{i+1}$ be defined by $$T(x) = \sum_{x \subset y,\\  y\in X_{i+1}} y$$ for $x \in X_i$. For all $i< n/2$, I need to show that ker$(T)=\{0\}$.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand : $X$ is a set of $n$ elements. Do you mean $X_i$ is the set of all $i-$ element subsets?

Comment: yes. sorry. I will edit it.